# Simple self-hosted website monitoring

Tags: monitoring, website, hosting

I'm looking for a simple self hosted website monitoring tool. It should be somthing similar to watchmouse.com or pimgdom.com, with a nice UI, colorful charts and so on (Customers like that :)). At the moment we use Zabbix also for HTTP monitoring, but since now our hoster care about the hardware and software monitoring on the machine directly, we don't need Zabbix anymore. For pure http-monitoring zabbix or an other monitoring suite is really an overkill.

So what I'm not looking for is:

Zabbix
Nagios
Hyperic
....
Sadly but the truth, after some hours of researching I wasn't able to find a fitting application. My hope is now on you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, when you say self hosted, do you mean installed and run on your servers?

Comment: Yesm this is what I mean :)

Answer (score 4):

Forget self hosting monitoring and use something like monitis - the big advantage is that it checks from multipel external (!) locations and is free / cheap, depending how you check.
This way you not only know that your HTTP server works well (it can cehck outout of specific URL's) but also that you are reachable from various international locations.

Comment: yup. self-monitoring is a contradiction in my opinion. if your network/host/etc is down, your monitor is likely afflicted by the same outage as the webserver....this almost necessarily must be done by a third-party

Answer (score 1):

How about awstats? http://awstats.sourceforge.net/ This can run on the webserver itself, analyses the logfiles and generates graphs. There's a bit of a learning curve first time you set it up, but when you've done it once its fairly simply to install on a new system.

Answer (score 0):

How about Circonus?

http://circonus.com/

I've used it before and it's the right mix of colourful graphs and monitoring. The have a hosted and non-hosted solution (Enterprise Agents) that may suit your needs.